# Why Chromium version 37 is shutting down when I search something on Google?

Tags: 14.04, chromium, lts

I recently upgraded form ubuntu 12.04 LTS to ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I did this because I had a problem with Chromium, whenever I'd open a new tab to search something on google the browser shut down. I started to get use to the flash problem, but this is a game changer,

Also, I thought it was a problem with the OS, partly because the system started to move a little bit slow. After the upgrade the same problem occurred, although the system started to run faster.

I currently have the following version of Chromium:  37.0.2062.94 Ubuntu 14.04 (290621) (64-bit)

Please give me some advice to make this problem stop. I have a lot of bookmarks in this browser and I use it to sync with the device from work.

Thx

Comment: Start chromium from command line and after it crashes see if you get a notice. What it most likely will be is an buggy extension. So you can also disable 1 extension at a time and see if it still crashes.

Comment: @Rinzwind thx for the advice. I disabled all extensions and the browser started to work again. It seems the extension that generated the crashes was Buffer 2.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled all extensions and the browser started to work again. It seems the extension that generated the crashes was Buffer 2.6.4. Problem solved, thx to @Rinzwind's advice.